# ClassCastException in Eclpse 3.5 and 3.6 when in Graphical Layout with a SlidingDrawer

Tags: android, eclipse, slidingdrawer

Has anyone got the Graphical Layout working correctly in either Eclipse 3.5 or 3.6 when using a Sliding Drawer?

I keep getting the following error in both:

***error!

ClassCastException: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup
Exception details are logged in Window > Show View > Error LogThe following classes could not be found:
- SlidingDrawer***

I get this error with my code and any example code you can find around:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#8CB69C">

    <SlidingDrawer
        android:id="@+id/drawer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:handle="@+id/handle"
        android:content="@+id/content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@id/drawerhandle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/drawerhandle"/>

    </SlidingDrawer>
</FrameLayout>
```

When I run the app on a device it works fine without any problems so it's got to be a problem with either Android SDK 8, Eclipse 3.5 and 3.6 or my workspace, I've know idea yet.  If it works fine for others then it's got to be something local.

Here's the exception stack details:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView cannot be cast to  android.view.ViewGroup
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:619)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:621)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:407)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:296)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.computeLayout(Bridge.java:397)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createLegacySession(LayoutLibrary.java:382)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:276)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.renderWithBridge(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.recomputeLayout(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.gle2.GraphicalEditorPart.activated(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.layout.LayoutEditor.pageChange(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.setActivePage(MultiPageEditorPart.java:1067)
at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor.setActivePage(FormEditor.java:607)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidXmlEditor.selectDefaultPage(Unknown Source)
at com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.editors.AndroidXmlEditor.addPages(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.ui.forms.editor.FormEditor.createPages(FormEditor.java:138)
at org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart.createPartControl(MultiPageEditorPart.java:348)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPartHelper(EditorReference.java:670)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.createPart(EditorReference.java:465)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPartReference.getPart(WorkbenchPartReference.java:595)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.EditorReference.getEditor(EditorReference.java:289)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditorBatched(WorkbenchPage.java:2863)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.busyOpenEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2768)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.access$11(WorkbenchPage.java:2760)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage$10.run(WorkbenchPage.java:2711)
at org.eclipse.swt.custom.BusyIndicator.showWhile(BusyIndicator.java:70)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2707)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2691)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.WorkbenchPage.openEditor(WorkbenchPage.java:2682)
at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:651)
at org.eclipse.ui.ide.IDE.openEditor(IDE.java:610)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:365)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.javaeditor.EditorUtility.openInEditor(EditorUtility.java:168)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:229)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.OpenAction.run(OpenAction.java:208)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.dispatchRun(SelectionDispatchAction.java:274)
at org.eclipse.jdt.ui.actions.SelectionDispatchAction.run(SelectionDispatchAction.java:250)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerActionGroup.handleOpen(PackageExplorerActionGroup.java:373)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.packageview.PackageExplorerPart$4.open(PackageExplorerPart.java:526)
at org.eclipse.ui.OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper$InternalListener.open(OpenAndLinkWithEditorHelper.java:48)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$2.run(StructuredViewer.java:845)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.JFaceUtil$1.run(JFaceUtil.java:49)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.SafeRunnable.run(SafeRunnable.java:175)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.fireOpen(StructuredViewer.java:843)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1131)
at org.eclipse.jface.viewers.StructuredViewer$6.handleOpen(StructuredViewer.java:1235)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.fireOpenEvent(OpenStrategy.java:264)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy.access$2(OpenStrategy.java:258)
at org.eclipse.jface.util.OpenStrategy$1.handleEvent(OpenStrategy.java:298)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.EventTable.sendEvent(EventTable.java:84)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Widget.sendEvent(Widget.java:1053)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.runDeferredEvents(Display.java:4066)
at org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display.readAndDispatch(Display.java:3657)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runEventLoop(Workbench.java:2640)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.runUI(Workbench.java:2604)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.access$4(Workbench.java:2438)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench$7.run(Workbench.java:671)
at org.eclipse.core.databinding.observable.Realm.runWithDefault(Realm.java:332)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.Workbench.createAndRunWorkbench(Workbench.java:664)
at org.eclipse.ui.PlatformUI.createAndRunWorkbench(PlatformUI.java:149)
at org.eclipse.ui.internal.ide.application.IDEApplication.start(IDEApplication.java:115)
at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppHandle.run(EclipseAppHandle.java:196)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:369)
at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:619)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:574)
at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1407)
```

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: I've a similar problem like you with my TabWidget- XML.
I used the Tab- tutorial with the given code, but got the 
"ClassCastException: com.android.layoutlib.bridge.MockView 
cannot be cast to android.view.ViewGroup".
Like you, i use Eclipse Helios

Did you solve this problem or did you find out, why this happens?

Comment: This problem isn't resolved yet, don't know if it's unique to me or a bug in the Eclipse plug-in for Android. I'm coming to the conclusion that the graphical layout engine is only capable of displaying basic layouts and has limitations.

Comment: Newer Android SDK/AVD out, still get the above error in the Graphical Layout with but if you set the Layout to Android 3.0 it works fine without any errors, that's better than nothing.

Comment: heh, that's correct... selecting "Android 3.0" from the target framework box (under "Create") shows the UI correctly !!  I have to say that I *hate* these lame bugs in the IDE !!! They're massive time wasters

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I got the same error but it turned out that I had mistaken the custom component class path in the XML file.
So, check that SlidingDrawer class is in the same package or - better - fully qualify the class. For example, try:

`<com.some.class.path.SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/drawer"`

Comment: Yep this fix's the problem, even for older versions of the ADT!!

Comment: Can tou mark this as answer if it has helped - StackOverflow is built on questions and answers. If an answer is satisfying for you, then it shall be marked as such

Comment: Sorry, I don't see how this fixes my problem... :-( What IS the correct class?? Tried android.widget.SlidingDrawer (as in Android specs), but that did not fix it at all! Is this a bug?? All other standard Android elements like TextView are found, why not SlidingDrawer??? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, this is a bug. I am not aware as to why this is happening. As a workaround - as noted above - select another UI designer target (>3)

Answer (score 1):

3.2 resolve the issue, there is still a warning "The graphics preview in the layout editor may not be accurate:
* Different corner sizes are not supported in Path.addRoundRect" but at the editor is completely usable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes even i got the same error and after searching for it over the net came to the conlcusion that its the Eclipse ADT plugin issue.

Answer (score 0):

In all your `xml` files, use strings as in the `@string/` command. When I replaced the `@string/` with a text string I got above error again.

Answer (score 0):

I noobed it up and had a `Button` inside of my `SurfaceView`.  In which case, the exception message is helpful.

```
android.view.*SomeView* cannot be cast to  android.view.ViewGroup
```

making the `Button` a sibling of the `SurfaceView` in my layout xml file resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have the layout defined completely

```
<SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:handle="@+id/handle"
    android:content="@+id/content">
```

Notice how the `android:handle="@+id/handle"` points at "handle", and `android:content="@+id/content"` points at content, however, you don't have any of those in SlidingDrawer. I guess you should define something like this:

```
<SlidingDrawer
    android:id="@+id/drawer"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:handle="@+id/handle"
    android:content="@+id/content">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/slideButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#fff" >
    </Button>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/contentLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:padding="10dip" >
    </LinearLayout>
</SlidingDrawer>
```